# Is there a way to access a complex model property of a page handler in the Razor page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I have a page handler that has a complex property for model binding. I want to access the property to the razor page so I can use the tag helpers to generate the form inputs from the property.

This is my page handler:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostChangePassword(PasswordChangeInput Input)
{
     // Some code

}
```

I want to access the property so I can use it with `asp-for`

```
@page
@model EditPasswordModel
@
{
    //Some code
}

<form method="post">
    <div class="flex justify-between my-1">
        <label class="text-gray-700" for="cus_name">Password:</label>
        <input asp-for="Input.Password" class="px-3 py-1 text-gray-900" />
    </div>
    <div class="flex justify-between my-1">
        <label class="text-gray-700" for="cus_name">Confirm Password:</label>
        <input asp-for="Input.ConfirmPassword" class="px-3 py-1 text-gray-900" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I am using ASP.NET Core Razor Pages

Answer (score 1):

In your `PageModel` class you need to add a `PasswordChangeInput` property with `[BindProperty]` attribute.

```
public class EditPasswordModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public PasswordChangeInput Input { get; set; }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostChangePassword()
    {
        // Input property will be populated from form
    }
}
```

And you also need to add asp-page-handler attribute to your form:

```html
<form method="post" asp-page-handler="ChangePassword">
    ...
</form>
```

**Edit:**

If you don't want to add the property to the `PageModel` you can pass it as parameter to the `OnPostChangePassword` handler:

```
public class EditPasswordModel : PageModel
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostChangePassword(PasswordChangeInput Input)
    {
        // Some code
    }
}
```

**BUT** now you won't be able to use input tag helpers to create the form using `asp-for="Input.Password"`. You must add the correct `name` attribute to the inputs manually:

```html
<form method="post" asp-page-handler="ChangePassword">
    <div class="flex justify-between my-1">
        <label class="text-gray-700" for="cus_name">Password:</label>
        <input name="Input.Password" class="px-3 py-1 text-gray-900" />
    </div>
    <div class="flex justify-between my-1">
        <label class="text-gray-700" for="cus_name">Confirm Password:</label>
        <input name="Input.ConfirmPassword" class="px-3 py-1 text-gray-900" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/model-binding#binding-complex-objects

Comment: Is there any way to access it without binding it in the class?

Comment: It is possible but then you can't use the `asp-for` attribute for the inputs. Updated the answer.